# SQLite - Exclude few column values while loading

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

I am using Xamarin.Forms and SQLite to develop an enterprise app. I need to show the table structure in UI. The class has around 10 properties (columns). But I need only 6 columns in UI table. The remaining four columns values should be loaded once user selects particular row as those four columns are heavy text blob graph data and I can't afford to load them all along with all rows. I am using this SQLite method `database.GetAllWithChildrenAsync<T>();` to load all rows and columns as of now. How to exclude those four column/property values while loading to avoid performance issues? Any help is appreciated as I haven't find much resources online on this.

Comment: define `<T>` without those columns

Comment: but we can specify  [Table("SomeTable")] attribute to one class only?

Comment: I've never tried, I don't see why you couldn't

Comment: I have splitted into two columns and trying using inheritance, both classes pointing to same Table.

Comment: I would just use two separate classes

Comment: @Jason I created two classes pointing to same table and it works! Thank you :)